# Change div with another div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have such a problem. On mouse enter, I want red circle to be changed with blue circle. But by this code, I have two circles on screen and red of them disappears on mouse enter. How to solve this problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.red').mouseenter(function(){ 
      $('.blue').show();
  }, function(){
        $('.red').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.red{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 150px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.blue{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 150px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circles">
    <div class="red">red circle</div>
    <div class="blue">blue circle</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just have one circle and then in mouse enter change the colour of the circle by class name or id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default hide the blue circle and bind mouse event on parent

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.blue').hide();

  $('.circles').mouseover(() => {
    $('.blue').show();
    $('.red').hide();
  });
  
  $('.circles').mouseleave(() => {
    $('.red').show();
    $('.blue').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.blue {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circles">
  <div class="red">red circle</div>
  <div class="blue">blue circle</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use 1 circle on which you toggle the `background-color` on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

```js
$('.circle').mouseenter((e) => $(e.target).css('background-color', 'rgb(0, 0, 255)'));
$('.circle').mouseleave((e) => $(e.target).css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'));
```

```css
.circle {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circles">
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

---

Since you [*Might Not Need Jquery*](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/), a pure JavaScript version of the above:

```js
const e = document.querySelector('.circle');
e.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => e.target.style.background = 'rgb(0, 0, 255)');
e.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => e.target.style.background = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)');
```

```css
.circle {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, it should help:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.red').mouseenter(function(){ 
        $('.blue').show();
        $('.red').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but at first I see also two circles instead of one. Is it possible to have red initially and change it with blue without changing the style properties of red circle? just replace one div with another

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achive, But as I undestood I've added the code. I hope this will help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.change').mouseenter(function(){ 
        $(this).addClass("blue");
        $(this).removeClass("red");
        $(this).html('Blue Circle');
    });
    
      $('.change').mouseleave(function(){ 
        $(this).addClass("red");
        $(this).removeClass("blue");
        $(this).html('Red Circle');
    });
});
```

```css
.red{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 150px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.blue{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 150px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="circles">
        <div class="change red">Red Circle</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```